# Построение графа с элементами имеющими более одного присоединения

Tags: c#, графы

Не могу с ходу придумать, как описать граф с узлами, которые должны иметь более одного входа.

Обычный направленный граф был бы набором экземпляров вот таких классов:

```
class Edge
{
  public int Weight { get; set; }
  public Node Node { get; set; } 
}

class Node
{
  public object Value { get; set; }
  public List<Edge> Outs { get; set; }
}
```

но что, если некоторые узлы должны иметь более одного входа (например, транзисторы)? Как описать структуру такого графа? Первое, что приходит на ум - сделать совокупность трех узлов. Но, может, есть подход интереснее?

**UPD:**

Я попытался изобразить свою хотелку графически и понял, что "первое что приходит на ум" является верным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первой картинке вообще не граф получился, у узла графа все входы должны быть устроены как один. На второй картинке как раз схематически изображен транзистор, однако я не могу придумать как это описать с точки зрения архитектуры. Добавить в граф совокупность узлов - не проблема. И обход будет верным (выход из транзистора будет иметь вес 1 либо 0 в зависимости от того, что пришло), однако проблема получается в том, как мне потом этот граф прочитать. Ведь при обходе я получу набор узлов, как я пойму, что имею дело именно с транзистором?

Comment: Для графа нет такого понятия, как "вход", есть только вершины и ребра, ребра могут быть ориентированными и иметь веса. Я не понимаю в чем ваша проблема. В википедии описан способы представления графов, просто выберите подходящий: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Граф_(математика)#Способы_представления_графа_в_информатике

Comment: @АндрейNOP, большое спасибо. Ни один не подошел

Answer (score 1):

У вершины орграфа не может быть никаких "входов". Поэтому надо делать не граф, а что-то еще.

К примеру, при моделировании электрических схем обычно выделяют узловые точки и элементы:

```
class Junction
{
    public List<Element> ConnectedElements { get; }
}

class Element
{
    public ElementType Type { get; }
    public List<Junction> ConnectedJunctions { get; }
}
```

Можно также отдельно выделить входы и выходы элементов, а также соединения между узлами:

```
class Junction
{
    public List<Connection> Connections { get; }
}

class Connection 
{
    public Junction From { get; }
    public Junction To { get; }
}

class Inlet : Junction
{
    public Element Element { get; }
}

class Outlet : Junction
{
    public Element Element { get; }
}

class Element
{
    public ElementType Type { get; }
    public List<Inlet> Inlets { get; }
    public List<Outlet> Outlets { get; }
}
```

Comment: Под входами я подразумевал точки входа ребра. И да, у графов их быть не может, ребро просто соединяет два узла. Я просто пытался внести некоторую ясность в свои хотелки. Теперь по поводу ответа. Я, имея схему, могу вручную сформировать граф с текущей схемой, я смогу сделать его обход с вычислениями (эмулируя движение тока), но я не смогу сделать обратную операцию. То есть из графа восстановить схему.

Comment: @iRumba вам не понадобится восстанавливать схему из графа если вы не будете нигде этот граф хранить

Comment: Я вам больше скажу, мне не просто надо его хранить, но и надо иметь некоторую стратегию его автоматического исправления

Comment: @iRumba зачем? Кто вас заставляет заниматься фигней?

Comment: В данном случае я сам. Задумка, генерировать схемы на основании обучения (вопрос + ожидаемый ответ). Ну либо исправлять ошибки в существующих

Comment: @iRumba все еще не понимаю зачем вам хранить граф

Comment: Ну не столько хранить сколько вывести в виде схемы. Сохранение просто частный случай вывода.

Comment: @iRumba зачем вам выводить граф в виде схемы, если вы можете вывести схему в виде схемы?

Comment: Я вас не понимать. Схема - частный случай графа. Разве нет?

Comment: @iRumba пожалуйста, прочитайте первый абзац моего ответа еще раз.

Comment: Чтобы из графа восстановить схему, вам скорее всего придется перейти к наследованию. Узлы схемы - это потомки некоторого базового "элемента". Причем каждый коннектор описывается соединенным с ним элементом и типом коннектора. Вам придется добавить отдельный элемент для "скрутики" проводов, и в этом случае у вы сможете свои элементы заменять на графические элементы схемы, а типы соединений будут подсказывать что вам рисовать присоединенным к какому коннектору.

Comment: @АлексейЛосев, я таки не понимаю, как описать транзистор. Он же имеет не просто 2 входа, они не равноценны

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну если не граф, значит мне нужно нечто, похожее на граф, что я смог бы обойти :)

Comment: @iRumba что вам мешает обойти структуру, приведенную в мое ответе?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ничего не мешает, но я не люблю подходы, когда у нас есть в уме соглашение (например о том, что если ElementType транзистор, то мы имеем 2 входа, причем разных по назначению). Я люблю ограничения. Я люблю инструменты, которые не позволяют ошибиться/запутаться во время разработки. Поэтому, подход рабочий, но я все еще в поисках и ожидании более изящного решения.

Comment: @iRumba ну так, если вы любите ограничения - используйте списки фиксированного размера